# Cannot use namespace as a type angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, ngrx, angular-services

I've got a service that I cannot make it work but it is very similar to another service that DOES work. It just give me the error:

> Cannot use namespace 'FeatureService' as a type.

I'm using angular 6 and ngrx on windows.

This is my effects file, that is giving me trouble. Its strange because I've got another similar service `CoreService` that does not give me that problem. And they are almost identical. Well, they are based in other modules, I'm not sure if that can make the difference.

```
import { FeatureService } from '../feature.services';
import { CoreService } from '../../core/core.services';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions<Action>,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private service: FeatureService,
    private service2: CoreService
  ) {}

}
```

And this is my service file:

```
@Injectable()
export class FeatureService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  retrieveProfileData(profileId: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get(SERVER_URL_STAGING2 + profileId);
  }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you please post the complete stack trace of the error you're getting?

Comment: I get the error while compiling 
`ERROR in src/app/features/profile/profile.effects.ts(25,22): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FeatureService' as a type.`

Comment: What do you have on `profile.effects.ts` Line 25?

Comment: The line I just wrote is incorrect: `private service: FeatureService,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found a solution. 
Since I already had the services working on the module core, I've created a new folder to add every service there, then I added the working service from core. Also I added my feature.service.ts to it, and then add those files to my index.ts on module core.

So, now i have these.

```
import { FeatureService } from '@app/core';
import { CoreService } from '@app/core';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions<Action>,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService,
    private service: FeatureService,
    private service2: CoreService
  ) {}
}
```

with the following index.ts file:

```
export * from './services/core.services'
export * from './services/features.services'
```

At the end I have the following file structure:

```
|-- app     
     |-- core
       |-- [+] authentication
       |-- services
           |-- core.ts  
           |-- features.ts  
       |-- core.module.ts  
       |-- index.ts  
     |-- features
       |-- profile
           |-- profile.efects.ts
```

I hope it helps someone.